# data between two php files

Tags: php

I have this php script:

```
<?php
include("simple_html_dom.php");
$url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thailand";
echo file_get_html($url);
?>
```

How can I send the $url variable to my tosql.php script ?

I apologize for not including more about what Im doing. Im actually sending this url to a jquery script which sends this to a php script titled tosql.php (which stores the processed data into mysql from the jquery script)

Comment: Call this PHP script before `tosql.php`.

Comment: You need to add more information.  What is `tosql.php`?  Why is this script an intermediary?  Why aren't you sending the URL directly to `tosql.php`?  **What is the intended result**?  **What have you tried already**?  **What has happened with what you've tried**?

Comment: or is there a way to pass the url via ajax to the jquery code? that would make things very smooth for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want.

```
<?php
$url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thailand";
include("simple_html_dom.php");
echo file_get_html($url);
?>
```

By declaring `$url` before your include, it's basically the same as declaring `$url` at the very top of `simple_html_dom.php`.

Comment: Gee, is that any different from my question->comment?

Comment: @Jared Farrish As an impartial 3rd party, I'd say yes it is different. You said _"do X"_.  @Chris said _"do X and here's the reason it works."_  On SO that makes a big difference. Had yours been an answer and not a comment, I would have upvoted this one and not yours.

Comment: @Micheal - You do realize you're talking about a comment and not an answer?

Comment: I apologize for not including more about what Im doing. Im actually sending this url to a jquery script which sends this to a php script titled tosql.php (which stores the processed data into mysql from the jquery script).

Comment: @Jared - amazingly, I had this thought completely independent of your comment. Shocker. SO is about giving... answers. If you're going to complain about my answer, go ahead and make yours into an answer too. Improve it with citations, links, and bullet points. Maybe some graphics. Nothing's stopping you, I'm certainly not.

Comment: @Praneet, that's completely different. I assumed that all of these scripts would be running within the same request. The easiest answer is probably to use session variables.

Comment: @Chris - Yeah, I guess I was griping without any reason. :)

Comment: @Micheal - Just because what you see doesn't say "edited" doesn't mean it wasn't edited to have more explanation. :) I honestly can't remember, but I hope I wouldn't have just posted a comment without any reason to say so. :)